# can't use HP STK after installing

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hp-proliant

I've downloaded HP STK from here http://www.hp.com/go/ProLiant/STK
I've tried to save the copy of my settings using such command, but got error:

```
C:\SWSetup\SP56837\x64\tools>hprcu.exe -a -s -f hprcu_settings.xml
HPRCU Version 1.00 - HP ROM Configuration Utility
Copyright (c) 2011 Hewlett-Packard Development Company, L.P.

ERROR: The Toolkit I/O Driver(hpsstkio.sys) is missing or not installed.

Return code: 3
```

I do see missing files here on my computer:

```
C:\SWSetup\SP56837\x64\drivers\winpe40\system\hpsstkio\hpsstkio.sys
C:\SWSetup\SP56837\x64\drivers\winpe30\system\hpsstkio\hpsstkio.sys
```

However I don't know why computer doesn't see them. I also have readme here

```
C:\SWSetup\SP56837\x64\drivers\readme.txt.
```

But it's very long and complicated.

I just wonder why after installing STK I can't use it? Am I really need to do something other than just install it? What exactly should I do?

**upd**: after reading "readme.txt" it seems I have to install something called "WinPE" and then i will be ale to install some sort of drivers that are required. The question is why should I do so much work? Isn't it easy just go to BIOS and modify what I need?

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy **hpsstkio.sys** to **c:\windows\system32\drivers** according to the documentation.